# Multiple Choice Menu Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to do a choice menu, each menu make different things, for example if you choice the number 1, will work good, but if you try to choose 2 or other number, first will try to run 1, and I don't want this. Is there a way to become "independent" for each option?

Example (this will work):

```
choice = input ("""
    1. Make thing 1
    2. Make thing 2
    3. Make thing 3
    4. Exit

    Please select your choice:""")

if choice == "1":
    print("thing 1")
if choice == "2":
    print("thing 2")
if choice == "3":
    print("thing 3")
if choice == "4":
    print("thing 4")
```

but, if 1 later has more coding, and you want to work with option 2, python will run also 1...

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm

Comment: This seems like a rather basic issue, have you done any debugging?

Comment: you should also read about `if` ... `elif` ... `else`

Comment: Based on your question, you described exactly what you need to do. If you chose 2, the 1st `if` statement would be false. Therefore, `else` would be the next statement to check if true. If you want to "nest" these, best case is to use elif as it will check to see the first condition that is true. Read the link in the first comment.

Comment: Removed some redundancies and improved grammar. However, as other commentators already said, you should look into basic `if`/`else` usage. FYI, other languages (C, C++, Java...) also have a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 5):

Python lacks a switch/case statement (like C/C++) in which you CAN have it perform multiple (adjacent) case conditions, and then have it `break` before processing further cases.  In Python you'll need to simulate using if-elif-else statements, perhaps utilizing comparison operators (like `==`, `<`) and/or boolean operators ( like `and`, `or`) in conditionals accordingly.

Here's an example of a C language switch/case [switch/case in python](https://bytebaker.com/2008/11/03/switch-case-statement-in-python/):

```
switch(n) {
  case 0:
    printf("You typed zero.\n");
    break;
  case 1:
  case 9:
    printf("n is a perfect square\n");
    break;
  case 2:
    printf("n is an even number\n");
  case 3:
  case 5:
  case 7:
    printf("n is a prime number\n");
    break;
  case 4:
    printf("n is a perfect square\n");
  case 6:
  case 8:
    printf("n is an even number\n");
    break;
  default:
    printf("Only single-digit numbers are allowed\n");
  break;
}
```

Here's how you might take a first crack at simulating the switch/case in Python [switch/case in python](https://bytebaker.com/2008/11/03/switch-case-statement-in-python/):

```
if n == 0:
    print "You typed zero.\n"
elif n == 1 or n == 9 or n == 4:
    print "n is a perfect square\n"
elif n == 2 or n == 6 or n == 8:
    print "n is an even number\n"
elif n == 3 or n == 5 or n == 7:
    print "n is a prime number\n"
elif n > 9:
    print "Only single-digit numbers are allowed\n"
```

And here's a much better, "Pythonic" way of doing it [switch/case in python](https://bytebaker.com/2008/11/03/switch-case-statement-in-python/):

```
options = {0 : zero,
           1 : sqr,
           4 : sqr,
           9 : sqr,
           2 : even,
           3 : prime,
           5 : prime,
           7 : prime,
}

def zero():
    print "You typed zero.\n"

def sqr():
    print "n is a perfect square\n"

def even():
    print "n is an even number\n"

def prime():
    print "n is a prime number\n"

options[num]()
```

Answer (score 0):

Good news for you, if you are still interested in using the switch case in Python.
you can now use `match` with Python 3.10

like this:

```py
    match n:
        case 0:
            print("You typed zero.\n")
        case "1":
            print("thing 1")
        case "2":
            print("thing 2")
        case "3":
            print("thing 3")
```

For more details read [click here to read this python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html)